# Raspberry PI 3 app stops updating after 40 minutes

Tags: freeze, glib

I'm working on an app for the Raspberry PI 3 running the latest Raspbian.  The app (from a terminal window) currently opens an Indy TCP Server, then begins pinging an FTP host (each ping is launched in its own thread and the next ping won't start until 15 seconds after the current one has completely finished), all the while displaying images on the screen and updating a label with the current time every minute.  Everything works great, then after 40 minutes the app looks like it has frozen and does no more updates; the system is still running just not updating.  I can click on the app and it doesn't change, but when I double click on a label that triggers an event, the app comes back to life and starts updating again.  When the app stops, it shows the following:
(fk30:1041): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 15519 was not found when attempting to remove it
Just looking for some general direction as to where I might start troubleshooting it..

Comment: Just noticed that the Wifi connection was down when I went to restart it...since I'm pinging through Wifi with Indy components could that causing the error perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

So, after much trial, it looks like the problem is due to some issue when the Pi goes into screen saver mode; somehow the updating the app does (likely to the screen) makes it throw those errors.

To disable screen saver permanently, do the following:

```
Open a Terminal window
Enter:  cd /etc/lightdm
Enter:  sudo pico lightdm.conf
Under:  [SeatDefaults]
Change:  #xserver-command=X
To:  xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
Enter:  CTRL X
Press:  y
Press:  ENTER
```

Now just reboot the system